# when computing your MAGI, do 529 contributions come off?

Tags: roth-ira, 529-plan

I have the exact same question as this: [Do 401K contributions reduce MAGI as it pertains to Roth IRA income limits?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16724/do-401k-contributions-reduce-magi-as-it-pertains-to-roth-ira-income-limits)

Except, instead of 401k, a 529.

Essentially, can I use a 529 to reduce my MAGI for the ROTH?

Answer (score 3):

> can I use a 529 to reduce my MAGI for the ROTH?

No. 529 contributions are not deductible at the federal level, so they would be included in your MAGI.